# Extra \else error

Tags: errors

I am wary of posting this as these extra \else posts seem to be getting closed, but here goes...

I getting the following errors when compiling my .tex file:

[image]

Line 243 is not being included in the output PDF and a whole blank page is being inserted above line 243. I have commented out many chunks from the .tex and compiling, in the hope of finding the error, but this has not found the error. So short of posting the entire .tex file, I cannot think of a way of posting a mwe.

One thing I have observed is that if I change the file name of my .tex file and compile, the errors do not occur. If I then run bibtex to add my bibliography to the file, then error does occur. Does this provide any clues?

This is my .aux file:

```
\relax 
\citation{LopesEtAl2006,Livezey2010}
\citation{Miller1983,BrazilIkenaga1987,ConnorsEtAl1993,Miller1996}
\citation{FunkEtAl2007,WennerbergEtAl2008,KupperEtAl2009,LopesEtAl2013}
\citation{EngelmoerRoselaar1998}
\citation{PraterEtAl1977}
\citation{HirschfieldEtAl2000,SchroederEtAl2008,Cramp1983,StClairEtAl2010}
\citation{BertrandEtAl2006,JohnsonEtAl2013,PriceWhalen2009}
\citation{Hart2001,Cuthill2006,StoddardStevens2011}
\select@language{english}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{english}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{english}}
\citation{Kilner1997}
\citation{BotJansen2013}
\citation{Surmacki2008}
\citation{BirdLifeInternational2013}
\citation{EngelmoerRoselaar1998,Cramp1983,GlutzvonBlotzheimEtAl1975,Vaurie1965,HaymanEtAl1991,Chandler2009}
\citation{Neumann1929,Johansen1961,EngelmoerRoselaar1998,Chandler2009}
\citation{PraterEtAl1977}
\citation{Garner2004}
\citation{BeamanMadge1998}
\citation{DoucetHill2009}
\citation{ArmentaEtAl2008}
\citation{FerreiraRasband2011}
\citation{PraterEtAl1977}
\citation{Cramp1983,EngelmoerRoselaar1998,HaymanEtAl1991}
\citation{WernhamEtAl2002}
\citation{EngelmoerRoselaar1998}
\citation{Amadon1949,PattenUnitt2002}
\citation{Donegan2012}
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Eigenvalues, proportion of variation explained and factor loadings of first two principal components outputted by one principal components analysis each of 1) hue, 2) saturation and 3) brightness\relax }}{4}}
\providecommand*\caption@xref[2]{\@setref\relax\@undefined{#1}}
\newlabel{loadings_df}{{1}{4}{Eigenvalues, proportion of variation explained and factor loadings of first two principal components outputted by one principal components analysis each of 1) hue, 2) saturation and 3) brightness\relax \relax }{}{}}
\newlabel{sub:summary}{{}{4}{\relax }{}{}}
\newlabel{sub:specimen_collection_location_two_categories}{{}{4}{\relax }{}{}}
\citation{PraterEtAl1977}
\citation{PiersmaJukema1993}
\citation{ArmentaEtAl2008}
\citation{Winker2000}
\citation{DoucetHill2009}
\citation{EevaEtAl2009}
\citation{GuillaumetEtAl2008,SurmackiEtAl2011}
\citation{Andersson1999,BrinkvanderBergNG2004,ShawkeyEtAl2006,ShawkeyEtAl2005}
\citation{}
\citation{PiersmaJukema1993}
\citation{HassallEtAl2011}
\citation{Greenwood1986}
\citation{TobiasEtAl2010}
\newlabel{sub:specimen_collection_location_four_categories}{{}{6}{\relax }{}{}}
\bibstyle{agsm}
\bibdata{refs}
\bibcite{Amadon1949}{{1}{1949}{{Amadon}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Andersson1999}{{2}{1999}{{Andersson}}{{}}}
\bibcite{ArmentaEtAl2008}{{3}{2008}{{Armenta et~al.}}{{Armenta, Dunn and\ Whittingham}}}
\bibcite{BeamanMadge1998}{{4}{1998}{{Beaman and\ Madge}}{{}}}
\bibcite{BertrandEtAl2006}{{5}{2006}{{Bertrand et~al.}}{{Bertrand, Faivre and\ Sorci}}}
\bibcite{BotJansen2013}{{6}{2013}{{Bot and\ Jansen}}{{}}}
\bibcite{BrazilIkenaga1987}{{7}{1987}{{Brazil and\ Ikenaga}}{{}}}
\bibcite{BrinkvanderBergNG2004}{{8}{2004}{{Brink and\ Van Der~Berg}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Chandler2009}{{9}{2009}{{Chandler}}{{}}}
\bibcite{ConnorsEtAl1993}{{10}{1993}{{Connors et~al.}}{{Connors, McCaffery and\ Maron}}}
\bibcite{Cramp1983}{{11}{1983}{{Cramp}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Cuthill2006}{{12}{2006}{{Cuthill}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Donegan2012}{{13}{2012}{{Donegan}}{{}}}
\bibcite{DoucetHill2009}{{14}{2009}{{Doucet and\ Hill}}{{}}}
\bibcite{EevaEtAl2009}{{15}{2009}{{Eeva et~al.}}{{Eeva, Sillanp{\"a}{\"a} and\ Salminen}}}
\bibcite{EngelmoerRoselaar1998}{{16}{1998}{{Engelmoer and\ Roselaar}}{{}}}
\bibcite{FerreiraRasband2011}{{17}{2011}{{Ferreira and\ Rasband}}{{}}}
\bibcite{FunkEtAl2007}{{18}{2007}{{Funk et~al.}}{{Funk, Mullins and\ Haig}}}
\bibcite{Garner2004}{{19}{2004}{{Garner}}{{}}}
\bibcite{GlutzvonBlotzheimEtAl1975}{{20}{1975}{{Glutz~von Blotzheim et~al.}}{{Glutz~von Blotzheim, Bauer and\ Bezzel}}}
\bibcite{Greenwood1986}{{21}{1986}{{Greenwood}}{{}}}
\bibcite{GuillaumetEtAl2008}{{22}{2008}{{Guillaumet et~al.}}{{Guillaumet, Crochet and\ Pons}}}
\bibcite{Hart2001}{{23}{2001}{{Hart}}{{}}}
\bibcite{HaymanEtAl1991}{{24}{1991}{{Hayman et~al.}}{{Hayman, Marchant and\ Prater}}}
\bibcite{HirschfieldEtAl2000}{{25}{2000}{{Hirschfeld et~al.}}{{Hirschfeld, Roselaar and\ Shirihai}}}
\bibcite{BirdLifeInternational2013}{{26}{2013}{{International}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Johansen1961}{{27}{1961}{{Johansen}}{{}}}
\bibcite{JohnsonEtAl2013}{{28}{2013}{{Johnson et~al.}}{{Johnson, Jordan~Price and\ Pruett-Jones}}}
\bibcite{Kilner1997}{{29}{1997}{{Kilner}}{{}}}
\bibcite{KupperEtAl2009}{{30}{2009}{{K{\"u}pper et~al.}}{{K{\"u}pper, Augustin, Kosztol{\'a}nyi, Burke, Flguerola and\ Sz{\'e}kely}}}
\bibcite{Livezey2010}{{31}{2010}{{Livezey}}{{}}}
\bibcite{LopesEtAl2013}{{32}{2013}{{Lopes et~al.}}{{Lopes, Alves, Gill, Gunnarsson, Hooijmeijer, Louren{\c {c}}o, Masero, Piersma, Potts, Raba{\c {c}}al et~al.}}}
\bibcite{LopesEtAl2006}{{33}{2006}{{Lopes et~al.}}{{Lopes, Marques and\ Wennerberg}}}
\bibcite{Miller1996}{{34}{1996}{{Miller}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Miller1983}{{35}{1983}{{Miller et~al.}}{{Miller, Gunn and\ Harris}}}
\bibcite{Neumann1929}{{36}{1929}{{Neumann}}{{}}}
\bibcite{PattenUnitt2002}{{37}{2002}{{Patten et~al.}}{{Patten, Unitt and\ Sheldon}}}
\bibcite{PraterEtAl1977}{{38}{1977}{{Prater et~al.}}{{Prater, Marchant and\ Vuorinen}}}
\bibcite{PriceWhalen2009}{{39}{2009}{{Price and\ Whalen}}{{}}}
\bibcite{SchroederEtAl2008}{{40}{2008}{{Schroeder et~al.}}{{Schroeder, Louren{\c {c}}o, Velde, Hooijmeijer, Both and\ Piersma}}}
\bibcite{ShawkeyEtAl2006}{{41}{2006}{{Shawkey et~al.}}{{Shawkey, Hill, McGraw, Hood and\ Huggins}}}
\bibcite{ShawkeyEtAl2005}{{42}{2005}{{Shawkey et~al.}}{{Shawkey, Mills, Dale and\ Hill}}}
\bibcite{StClairEtAl2010}{{43}{2010}{{St~Clair et~al.}}{{St~Clair, Kuepper, Herrmann, Woods and\ Szekely}}}
\bibcite{StoddardStevens2011}{{44}{2011}{{Stoddard and\ Stevens}}{{}}}
\bibcite{Surmacki2008}{{45}{2008}{{Surmacki}}{{}}}
\bibcite{SurmackiEtAl2011}{{46}{2011}{{Surmacki et~al.}}{{Surmacki, Siefferman and\ Yuan}}}
\bibcite{TobiasEtAl2010}{{47}{2010}{{Tobias et~al.}}{{Tobias, Seddon, Spottiswoode, Pilgrim, Fishpool and\ Collar}}}
\bibcite{Vaurie1965}{{48}{1965}{{Vaurie}}{{}}}
\bibcite{WennerbergEtAl2008}{{49}{2008}{{Wennerberg et~al.}}{{Wennerberg, Marthinsen and\ Lifjeld}}}
\bibcite{WernhamEtAl2002}{{50}{2002}{{Wernham et~al.}}{{Wernham, Siriwardena, Toms, Marchant, Clark and\ Baillie}}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Location of collection of Curlew specimens}}{11}}
\newlabel{fig:plots_specimen_locations}{{1}{11}{Location of collection of Curlew specimens\relax }{}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Density of four principal components of coloration in \textit  {orientalis} and \textit  {arquata}}}{12}}
\newlabel{fig:plot_coloration_density}{{2}{12}{Density of four principal components of coloration in \textit {orientalis} and \textit {arquata}\relax }{}{}}
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Results of linear regression to determine which variables predicted hue, saturation an brightness of Curlew specimens. Origin of collection is split into two groups: specimens collected within range of orientalis or arquata.\relax }}{13}}
\newlabel{oricoll_lm}{{2}{13}{Results of linear regression to determine which variables predicted hue, saturation an brightness of Curlew specimens. Origin of collection is split into two groups: specimens collected within range of orientalis or arquata.\relax \relax }{}{}}
\@writefile{lot}{\contentsline {table}{\numberline {3}{\ignorespaces Results of linear regression to determine which variables predicted hue, saturation an brightness of Curlew specimens. Origin of collection is split into two groups: specimens collected within Europe, Africa/Middle East, Asia or India.\relax }}{13}}
\newlabel{oricoll_subgroup_lm}{{3}{13}{Results of linear regression to determine which variables predicted hue, saturation an brightness of Curlew specimens. Origin of collection is split into two groups: specimens collected within Europe, Africa/Middle East, Asia or India.\relax \relax }{}{}}
\newlabel{fig:sub1}{{\caption@xref {fig:sub1}{ on input line 432}}{15}{\relax }{}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3}{\ignorespaces Examples of specimen used in studies. Red circles show the locations on the breast, scapulars and crown of hue, saturation and brightness measurement\relax }}{15}}
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{15}}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{15}
\gdef\lastpage@lastpageHy{}
\ttl@finishall
```

And this is .cls file:

```
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% Conference proceedings and article templates for
% personal open-archiving activities
% September 2012
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{SelfArx}[25/01/2012, v1.0]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
.cls
\RequirePackage{times}      % Loads the Times-Roman Fonts
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}   % Loads the Times-Roman Math Fonts
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}      % Needed to pick between latex and pdflatex

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

%%%%% for abstract+authors frames 


% ---------------------------------------------------------------------       
% margins         
\RequirePackage[left=2cm,%
                right=2cm,%
                top=2.25cm,%
                bottom=2.25cm,%
                headheight=11pt,%
                letterpaper]{geometry}%
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf,sf},%
                labelsep=period,%
                justification=raggedright]{caption}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}  % Needed to define custom headers/footers
\RequirePackage{lastpage}  % Number of pages in the document
\pagestyle{fancy}          % Enables the custom headers/footers
% Headers
\lhead{}%
\chead{}%
\rhead{\small\sffamily\bfseries\@PaperTitle\  --- \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% Footers
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% % No footer rule
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% section/subsection/paragraph set-up
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering\arabic{section}. #1}}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\color{color1}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{color2!10}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\centering#1}}}
  []  
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []    
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\sffamily\small\bfseries}
  {}
  {0em}
  {#1} 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{10pt}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% tableofcontents set-up
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\hfill\thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents{subsection}[\tocsep]
  {\addvspace{2pt}\small\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}[\tocsep]
  {\footnotesize\sffamily}
  {}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]  
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------  
% Get the multiple author set
\newcount\@authcnt
\newcount\@tmpcnt\@tmpcnt\z@

\def\@affiliation{%
  \ifnum\@tmpcnt<\@authcnt
   \global\advance\@tmpcnt1
    \raggedright \csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@tmpcnt\endcsname\hfill\\%
   \let\next\@affiliation \vskip1pt
  \else
   \let\next\relax
  \fi
\next}

\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{%
    \global\advance\@authcnt1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname @auth\romannumeral\the\@authcnt\endcsname
    {#1}}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nolistsep} % Uncomment to remove spacing between items in lists (enumerate, itemize)
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\bfseries\color{color1}\textsuperscript{[#1]}}
%\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0cm}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\PaperTitle}[1]{\def\@PaperTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\Archive}[1]{\def\@Archive{#1}}
\newcommand{\Authors}[1]{\def\@Authors{#1}}
\newcommand{\JournalInfo}[1]{\def\@JournalInfo{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1]{\def\@Abstract{#1}}
\newcommand{\Keywords}[1]{\def\@Keywords{#1}}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\twocolumn[{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\colorbox{color2!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-3.5\fboxsep-3.5\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty
\sffamily\small\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract
\else
\sffamily\small\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[5pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
\fi
}%
}%
\vskip5pt%
\begingroup%
\raggedright\sffamily\small%
\footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
\endgroup%%
}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}]%
}%
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\let\oldbibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace*{-\tocsep}\refname}%
\oldbibliography{#1}%
\setlength\itemsep{0pt}%
}
```

Any advice appreciated

Comment: We need more information, really.

Comment: Yes, we really do. Please prepare a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)

Comment: make a copy of the file(s) and strip the copy until the error is gone; undo your last change, and you'll be close to a mwe

Comment: I've now commented out different sections of entire .tex file, plus various parts of .cls and .aux file, but errors remain. I've uploaded .cls and .aux file in hope somebody might be able to see where error is arising.

Comment: Please note edit regarding when error occurs, therefore, error does not occur the first time after I change file name of .tex file but does occur after the first time I run bibtex. Does this give a clue?

Comment: As noted above we need to see your (cut down) `.tex` file (and perhaps `.bib` file - the `.aux` and `.cls` file are not enough.  The `.tex` file tells us which packages you are loading with which options and shows whether you are redefining any internals.